# Flutter | Input from sliders saved locally

Tags: flutter

So,

I would like to recreate the below screenshot (ignore the auto transition timer):

[image: The screenshot:]

It is a timer. And the sliders are needed to set the timers.

My question is: how can I take the inputs from the 3 sliders and save them locally only if the "save" button?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your sliders in a stateful widget and use setstate to update each slider value.on saving write to your local database

some resources on local database
[flutter cookbooks](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)
[databases available](https://blog.logrocket.com/choosing-right-database-flutter-application/)

```
double slider1 = 20;
double slider2=30;

// your sliders
Slider(
      value:slider1,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
      label:slider1.round().toString(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
         slider1 = value;
        });
      },
    )

Slider(
      value:slider2,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
      label:slider2.round().toString(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
         slider2 = value;
        });
      },
    )


// saving the data 
...
onPressed:(){
/// your database
MydatabsesaveSliderValues(slider1:slider1,slider2:slider2)...
```